# iOS Location Background Mode Running Time

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

We are doing some work with beacons and iOS and investigating the options for applying a debounce between when we first go in range of the beacon and when we raise a notification to the user.

So the flow would be,

1. Go in range of a beacon.
2. Start a timer.
3. Timer expires, post notification.

Their doesn't seem to be any complications doing this when the app is in the foreground but I'm not sure how this will work with the app closed.

If we register the location background mode then the app will get started when we go in range of a beacon but its unclear to me how long the app we'll be allowed to run. If the app is only allowed to run for a very short period of time then we won't have time to start a timer and have it expire.

Can anyone shed any light on how much execution time the location background mode allows an app when started in the background like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that once you enter the beacon region that you start ranging the beacon - this will provide you with ranging callbacks at the rate of one per second - even if your app is in the background. You can count these events and use that to determine when you will post the notification. At this point you can stop ranging the beacon.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region];
    self.beaconCount=0;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [manager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
               inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
        self.beaconCount++;
        if (self.beaconCount > SOME_THRESHOLD) {
            [manager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
            [self postLocalNotification];
        }
}
```

Because this is using the location background mode there is no overall limit to the amount of background time available, but there is a limit on each invocation of a delegate method of a few seconds - but this code won't be anywhere near that.

Comment: ranging in background also won't last forever. when background execution time expires, ranging will stop.

Comment: No, if you have specified location background mode (and requested "always" authorisation on iOS 8) then you can range in the background indefinitely, just as you can monitor for regions.  Regardless you only need to range for a few seconds to determine that you are in range of the beacon and then you can display the alert and end ranging.  I will update my answer with some example code

Comment: @Paulw11, are you sure that you can indefinitely range in the background in iOS 8 with UIBackgroundModes location set in your plist?  I have tried this, but only get 10 seconds of background ranging time as in iOS 7.  See my test app here:  https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/ibeacon-background-demo/tree/ios8  Of course, you can get monitoring change updates indefinitely in the background, and then range for 10 seconds on each of these events.  But I do not believe you can continue to range indefinitely in the background.

Comment: I will clarify my answer - you can range for long enough to add the hysteresis that they are looking for - ie determine that they are in the region, not just walked past the beacon

Answer (score 1):

You can use local notifications for this purpose. There is no guarantee how long your app will continue running in background. If you want to know how much time the OS gives you, you can check UIApplication's backgroundTimeRemaining property.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/backgroundTimeRemaining